# Windows 2008 R2 Time Sync Between DCs

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, time-synchronization, w32time

Our domain has three domain controllers, two of which are Windows 2008 R2, with a third that runs 2003 R2.

- DC1 (2008 R2, PDC Emulator, Syncs
  with external time source)
- DC2 (2008 R2)
- DC3 (2003 R2)

According to `w32tm /monitor`

- DC2 is currently +654.6040905s from DC1
- DC3 is currently +0.0258444s from DC1

It would appear as though DC3 syncs fine, but DC2 drifts by a couple of minutes per month.

How can I fix the synchronisation between DC2 and DC1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found below article from Google, may be that might Help you......

AD automatically sets each DC to sync time with the master DC. In order to make sure the master DC has the proper time and is set to be an available & reliable time source, run the following commands:

NET TIME /SETSNTP:time.windows.com

NET STOP W32TIME

NET START W32TIME

W32TM /config /reliable:YES

W32TM /resync /rediscover Next, run the following command on the other DCs.

W32TM /resync /rediscover

And you're done!

Comment: Thanks. I did the above (with exception to the first line, as I already have an alternative time source), but when I ran the last line on the other DCs, that generated the error detailed in this KB article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929276/en-gb. Thanks, now resolved.

Comment: How long does it take for clients computers to be aware of the changes on the DCs? I want to make sure the clients aren't too far out of sync from the DCs such that Kerberos fails to auth.